# Is spring-boot jar can be work with existing spring session based project ? . is it possible?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I try put spring-boot jar file into spring session based application. we have enterprise edition, so we planned to add new features as jar. is it possible?. 
give your instructions how to do it?

we developed and include in spring project but it was not call the repository.
it  shows the "creating error in bean message".

Comment: Autoconfiguration may not work in spring based project. you need to configure spring session related beans. sample for your reference [spring session configuration](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-session-samples/blob/master/inmemory/spring-session-cookie-strategy/src/main/java/com/barath/app/configuration/SessionConfiguration.java)

Comment: i couldn't get you. can you explain in details ? . i want sample code how spring boot jpa crud  project is added as dependency to spring mvc session project.